# RestFB get Reactions on a Url

Tags: restfb

I see that RestFB has added access to Reactions in the Post, Photo and Video objects, but it does not seem to have access from a Url. What would be the best way to get the Reactions on a Url? Do I need to call the Graph API directly?

Comment: Can you please point to the Graph API Reference where this is mentioned? I don't see reactions here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.7/url

Comment: Apparently its not mentioned in the API Reference, but if I make the call with the id of a url object, I get the reactions back.

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/926956854006323/reactions?access_token=[token-value]&format=json&method=get&pretty=0&debug=all&suppress_http_code=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RestFB does not support reactions on open graph objects. So you should call the opengraph id as you mentioned in the comment above and work with the `fetchConnection` call. As Type you should use `Reactions.ReactionItem`.

```
Connection<Reactions.ReactionItem> con = 
    client.fetchConnection("<ogid>/reactions", Reactions.ReactionItem.class);
```

I think this should work. The code is untested ;)

Comment: How to get `<ogid>` with RestFB if I have only post url?

Comment: Sorry I mean how do you get post `ID` from its url with RestFB? 
if you have a url of a post, page or personal account how do you get the id from it using RestFB?